# Laravel: Change View with interaction from a different device

Tags: laravel, post, view, model, controller

On one of my Laravel pages I am generating a QR Code. This QR Code contains a unique session hash, which is later used to associate a phone_id to a session_hash.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ3rC.png

After being scanned by my Android application, I am synchronizing data with my Laravel database, successfully.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8jJ0.png

My objective is to change the page, from the one displaying the QR Code, to one displaying the database contents, on the moment the controller (which is accessed through a POST request on my android device) finishes executing.

How would I go about changing views after scanning the QR Code?

Answer (score 0):

Your QR-Code view can make ajax request in a loop to laravel. Your server will check if there is a new entry for the generated qr code. If so, it will return an okay to change the page.

Another approach would be the realization with websockets, but is more complicated than an ajax request.

Comment: How would I go about accomplishing this, using the Ajax Request?